# Error when attempting to mount NFSv4 file system

Tags: filesystems, rhel, nfs

I am having a problem mounting an NFS v4 share on a RHEL6 system, when attempting to mount the file system with the command "mount -t nfs4 nfsserver:/home /media/home" I receive the following error message

mount.nfs: mount system call failed

I have other RHEL6 and Ubuntu systems that can mount this file system with no issue (same command). The strange part is that I can mount the file system from that server by forcing it to use NFS v3. I have checked the exportfs file, DNS, restarted the various NFS services with no change, SELinux and iptables have also been disabled while testing. The remote NFS server is also running RHEL6. I'm probably missing something obvious but not sure what to look for next, any ideas would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can add '-v' to the mount command to get more details.  Also, you might want to check your logs and whether you've got all the same RPC services running as on the working systems.

Comment: That helped out a bit - this issue was related to some IPv6 configuration issues, while the systems worked (could ssh, etc. via an IPv6 address) NFS did not. After some investigation it turned out to be an incorrectly configured firewall that was blocking traffic. Once that was figured out everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to a hardware firewall that was not configured correctly for IPv6. Some additional steps I followed to help troubleshoot were to look at both iptables and ip6tables on both systems, even though IPv4 and IPv6 were working I needed to verify both protocols and the ports for both protocols. In this instance IPv4 and NFSv4 worked but not on IPv6, when using the name it always used the IPv6 address.